# Vacuum Manifold of an $SU(2)$ Theory

Tags: gauge-theory, field-theory, topology, topological-field-theory, solitons

I am reading Coleman's book "Aspects of Symmetry", specifically chapter 6 "Classical Lumps and their Quantum Descendants". He gives an Example 5 p. 209 for the topological solutions for an $SU(2)$ theory, I copy the complete example below. He considers a theory of $SU(2)$ gauge fields and scalar fields.

> "The [gauge] group is $SU(2)$, and the scalar fields transform like a complex isospinor, $K$. The zeros of $U$ [the potential] are all fields such that $\bar{K}K$ is some positive number, $a^2$. (This is the Weinberg-Salam model, without leptons and without the $U(1)$ gauge field.)
>   If we write the two-component complex $K$ field in terms of four real fields, we see that $G/H$ [the vacuum manifold] is a hypersphere, $S^3$. All mappings from $S^2$ to $S^3$ are homotopic to the trivial mapping, [...] Thus there are no non-trivial topological conservation laws."

I *think* I understand this, but there are some nagging doubts in my mind. The gauge group is $G=SU(2)$. Now we want $H$, the group that leaves vacua invariant. I think that this is just the identity element. My reasoning is as follows: $SU(2)$ is the group of rotations of two component complex vectors. There is no element except the identity that can leave such a vector invariant, since the only such rotation there could be would be a rotation about the axis of the vector, which would require rotating into a higher dimesion than $SU(2)$ can access (I imagine the usual two-dimensional vector arrows in a plane, we cannot rotate around the axis of such a vector without including three dimesnional rotations, hence for $SO(2)$ we have a similar situation). This reasoning seems shaky to me at best. First, the vectors we act on with $SU(2)$ are complex, not real, so my imagining them as simple arrows in a plane seems simplisitc. Second, $SU(2)$ is a double cover of $SO(3)$ which certainly has elements apart from the identity that leave vectors invariant, they are the elements that rotate around the axis of the vector. *If* $H$ is just the identity, then we have the required $G/H=SU(2)/\{I\}\cong SU(2)\cong S^3$ as required.

Furthermore, in the next example he states that if the gauge group $G$ is any compact connected Lie group, and $H$ is any discrete subgroup, all mappings of a sphere into $G/H$ are homotopic to the trivial mapping (if anyone can direct me to a proof of this as well that would be fantastic) and states that the previous example (the one I copied above) is a specific case of this. The point I take away from this is that $H$ must be a discrete subgroup, which of course ${I}$ by itself is.

Comment: Coleman tells you the vacuum manifold is 3-dimensional, a 3-sphere, so *O(4)/O(3)* just as in the Higgs potential of the SM, doesn't he?

Comment: The group formed by the equivalence classes of the maps from the sphere $S^2$ to the quotient space $G/H$ - aka the second homotopy group $\pi_2(G/H)$ - is actually isomorphic to group whose elements are given by the equivalence classes of the maps from the circle $S^1$ to the group $H$ - aka the fundamental group $\pi_1(H)$. If $H$ is a discrete group then [its fundamental group of a discrete group is trivial](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34713/fundamental-group-of-a-finite-set-with-discrete-topology)

Comment: @Diracology A small bit of nitpicking... that statement is not true in general (consider the quotient $U(2)/U(1) \cong S^3$).  However, it is true if the map $\pi_1(H) \to \pi_1(G)$ induced by the inclusion $H \to G$ is trivial, in particular, if $\pi_1(H) = 0$, so your argument still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general element in $SU(2)$ is $ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b^* & a^* \end{pmatrix} $ it will act on a spinor  $ \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix} $. I want to see what can stabilize this spinor so the following equation must be true $$ ac + bd = c \\ -b^*c + a^*d = d $$. This at the very least implies $ bd =0 $ and $ -b^*c =0$ Also we must have $ a = a^* =1 $ . Now we can surely stabilize the spinor if $ b=0$ giving us the identity element. Suppose we assume $ b \neq 0 $. Then this means c an d must be zero giving us the zero vector. If we exclude the zero vector then the isotropy group of a general spinor has to consist of just the identity element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a further query. It seems to me that in general with finding soliton solutions one does not even need to know the form of the potential, simply what the gauge group is and how the scalar fields transform. This seems sufficient to determine G/H. To me this makes sense because the exact form of the potential is heavily constrained by gauge invaiance (so just by knowing the gauge group you have some information on the potential automatically)...

Comment: ...However I could imagine there might be cases where the form of the vacuum fields are such that there are additional transformations that leave them invariant (i.e. there are transformations that don't leave a general $\phi$ invariant, but do leave a vacuum $\phi$ invariant) and hence $H$ is larger than you might expect if you just knew $G$ and how the scalar fields transformed, and to know $H$ you would indeed need to know the potential (but if you know the potential you can directly determine $G/H$, making the whole effort of finding just $H$ pointless). Is this a valid line of reasoning?